# How could I show X & Y mouse position while the mouse is moving with Graphics2D?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, awtrobot

How could I show X & Y mouse position while the mouse is moving with Graphics2D?

I'm trying to show the coordinates when the mouse is moving, but I can do it with `System.out.println`, I have in mind using `drawString.join("", 10, 5)`.

How could I reach that then?

*Here's what I did

```
public class Bell2 extends JPanel {
    static JFrame frame=new JFrame();


    public Bell() {

    }

     public void paint(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
            //Here's where I struggle
            g2.drawString.join ("mouseX, mouseY, C");


     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame.setSize(500,300);
        frame.setLocation(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);

         Robot robot = null;
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              Color c = robot.getPixelColor(456,141);


        double mouseY=1.0;
        double mouseX=1.0;
        while(mouseX !=0 || mouseY  !=0) {

            mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
             mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();

             System.out.println("x: "+mouseX+" y: "+mouseY+" c: "+c);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) *"I got 3 questions here"* Only one question should be here. Move the other two to separate (appropriately titled) question threads. (Voting to close as 'too broad'). 2) Using `Robot` is unnecessary. Instead add a `MouseMotionListener` to the relevant component. 3) The correct method for custom painting a `JComponent` (like `JPanel`) is `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it now, you're right about Robot and MouseMotionListener, but, talking fairly close to this code, how could I use a custom color that is inside the main, to a method that is out of main for example a paint method? I was told with return could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but, alternatively, you could consider doing something like this, if you want to stay fairly close to your original example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.setSize(500,300);
        frame.setLocation(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);

        try {
            final Robot robot = new Robot();
            handleMouse(robot);
        } catch (final AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void handleMouse(final Robot robot) {
        int mouseX = 1;
        int mouseY = 1;
        while (mouseX !=0 || mouseY !=0) {
            final Point mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            mouseX = mouseLocation.x;
            mouseY = mouseLocation.y;
            final Color currentColor = robot.getPixelColor(mouseX, mouseY);
            System.out.println(String.format("x: %d, y: %d, c: %s", mouseX, mouseY, currentColor));
        }
    }
```

Note that the `currentColor` is getting updated *each time* the `mouseX` and `mouseY` are; this was not the case in your original snippet.

Another thing to note if you're watching the output on the terminal - the color will only appear to change if `mouseX` and `mouseY` remain <= 255; beyond that value, you'll likely only see this output:

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
```

Comment: Ok, that's right, and how should it work with graphics2D, I mean string.join("", 10, 10);?

Comment: Are you trying to call this method? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int) if that's the case, you want to pass some `String` along with the coordinates... e.g.,
`final String stringToDraw = String.format("%d, %d, %s", mouseX, mouseY, color);`
`g2.drawString(stringToDraw, mouseX, mouseY);`

Comment: That's right, but look, I'm struggling with the paint method, I try to use the Color variable (robot.getPixelColor), and I can't, I says that I need to create a local variable, a way to bring color from the loop while, and that's the part I don't know